# Which Tumblr themes handle <pre> tags well?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm interested in knowing which Tumblr themes handles `<pre>` tags well by default, meaning that one won't have text flowing out of the screen. For so many that I've checked, I have to add CSS on the *Advanced* tab:

```
pre {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: With reference to your other question this should read "handle pre tags well?"

Answer (score 2):

From what I see you have "code" there; You can add a Syntax Highlighter script or something.

See [here](http://blog.noemalzieu.com/post/2187104751/tumblr-et-syntaxhighlighter) for a possible solution (it's in french, but you can use Google Translate)

Or, another thing I found: http://drnicwilliams.com/2007/03/08/syntax-highlighting-in-tumblr/

Comment: I've improved the Question.